# Ajax Get Data on Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm really new to MVC hope you can give me a detailed instructions on this.

I have a query in my repository that returns pending users who have a certain role_id. Now my issue is this I when the administrator clicks on the anchor tag of id `idMessenger` below

```
 <li> <a href="#" id="idMessenger">Messenger<span class="label label-danger pull-right">{{$messenger->count()}}</span></a> </li>
```

I want to show the pending messengers only in the

```
<div class="col-md-2 left-aside">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <ul class="inbox-nav capitalize-font">
      <li><a href="#" id="all-pending">All Pending Applications</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#" id="idClient">Clients<span class="label label-danger pull-right">{{$elderly->count()}}</span></a></li>
      <li> <a href="#" id="idMessenger">Messenger<span class="label label-danger pull-right">{{$messenger->count()}}</span></a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.left-aside-column-->
<div class="col-md-10 right-aside">
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="datable_1" class="table  display table-hover contact-list" data-page-size="10">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Appication ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Senior Citizen Number</th>
            <th>Role/Submitted as</th>
            <th>Date of Submission</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach($allPending as $user)
          <tr>
            <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->scn}}</td>
            <td><span class="label label-danger">{{$user->roles->name}}</span></td>
            <td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
            <td>
              <a href="{{route('approveUser', $user->id)}}" class="text-inverse" title="Approve" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Approve</a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="{{route('deleteUser', $user->id)}}" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you please teach me how to do it in ajax.

Comment: There are some resources teaching that online. Just google it first. Example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm

Comment: put html in seperate blade and call it in iframe. Use Modal show event and fetch data from db via ajax.

Comment: +Bugfixer, Sir, I'm really a newbie with regards to this. Can you please give me some references and tips on how to start with this.